# Doing something wrong with my Entity Update.Code

Tags: c#, asp.net, .net, entity-framework, entity-framework-6

I have a GridView with a select button that triggers this code. The intent of it is to provide a last minute means to reverse a authorization. Therefore what it is attempting to do I is open a table in the database, updated three columns setting two to null (no absolutely necessary could be blank or left alone for that matter) but the crucial one to change is 'Approved' which needs to be changed to False. I'm red lining of all of my value assignments and my 'SaveChanges()'.  I'm very new to coding in c# so I could use some direction here but what I have done here follows what examples I have found and I'm thinking it should be working ... BUT...

Thoughts?

```
        protected void PrePushUpdatesGrd_SelectedIndexChanged(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        GridViewRow row = PrePushUpdatesGrd.SelectedRow;
        int trackingID = int.Parse(row.Cells[1].Text);

        using (CInTracDBEntities1 Context = new CInTracDBEntities1())
            {
                var UpdateSet = Context.Updates.Where(a => a.CAssetID == trackingID).Select(x => new { x.CAssetID, x.SubmitBy, x.SubmitDT, x.ApproveBy, x.Approved, x.ApprovedDT }).FirstOrDefault();
                    UpdateSet.ApproveBy = null;
                    UpdateSet.ApprovedDT = null;
                    UpdateSet.Approved = "False";

                    trackingID.SaveChanges();
            }

        PrePushUpdatesGrd.DataBind();            
    }
```

Comment: trackingID is int  how can you use .SaveChanges() method on int?

Comment: As it is currently, the `UpdateSet` variable does not contain an entity, but an anonymous type, thus cannot be used for updating. How about removing the `Select(...)`?

Comment: @DespeiL - I was following an example that I found. I would have thought that I would have only had 'SaveChanges()' by itself but the example I was looking at used the same variable there that had been used above where trackingID is referenced earlier in the code. This was the only reason I put it there. NOTE: I'm new new new to c# and have had not formal training with it so that's why I'm a bit lost here. All three of the value assignments (the two nulls and the false are redlining on the left side of the equal sign and SaveChanges is redlined.

Comment: @IvanStoev - if I removed the select then I wouldn't be updating the proper record would I?   Or perhaps how should ask that is would be better stated... How would I properly designate what record to update without a select?

Comment: @KenCarter It's exactly the opposite. And you don't need `Select` when using LINQ method syntax - it's required only by the query syntax, and even there you would select the **whole** object, e.g. `(from u in Context.Updates where u.CAssetID == trackingID select u).FirstOrDefault()` (notice the `select u`). But method syntax allows you to use simply `var UpdateSet = Context.Updates.FirstOrDefault(u => u.CAssetID == trackingID);`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this

```
protected void PrePushUpdatesGrd_SelectedIndexChanged(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    GridViewRow row = PrePushUpdatesGrd.SelectedRow;
    int trackingID = int.Parse(row.Cells[1].Text);

    using (CInTracDBEntities1 Context = new CInTracDBEntities1())
        {
            var UpdateSet = Context.Updates.FirstOrDefault(a => a.CAssetID == trackingID);
                UpdateSet.ApproveBy = null;
                UpdateSet.ApprovedDT = null;
                UpdateSet.Approved = "False";
                Context.Entry(UpdateSet).State= EntityState.Modified; //correct
                Context.SaveChanges();

        }

    PrePushUpdatesGrd.DataBind();            
}
```

Comment: Choking on 'IsModified' trying to figure out why right now.

Comment: sory  my falt i forgot that I use custom context object) I update my answer

Comment: Okay, now both modelItem and EntityState are showing up not existing in the current state.

Comment: modelItem is your model so in this case it will be UpdateSet

Comment: Oh duh, so that was a key word for me and I was too stupid to catch it... sorry.. Is EntityState similar and I'm missing that as well?

Comment: EntityState is enum)

Here is EF tutorial http://www.entityframeworktutorial.net/EntityFramework5/entity-framework5-introduction.aspx